# Set Mac Address in QEMU/KVM properties file

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, mac-address, qemu

I'm trying to set the mac address for my virtual machine in the virtual machine properties file. The properties file '102.conf' currently looks like this:

```
name: vm1.mydomain.com
bootdisk: ide0
ostype: w2k8
ide0: local:102/vm-102-disk-1.raw
memory: 1500
sockets: 1
ide1: local:iso/virtio-win-0.1-mm34.iso,media=cdrom
vlan0: rtl8139=96:83:DA:A0:06:34
```

Where and how in this file can I set the mac address for my virtual machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line

```
vlan0: rtl8139=96:83:DA:A0:06:34
```

the `96:83:DA:A0:06:34` is a MAC address. Changing that value should change your MAC address.

If you are generating your own MAC addresses you should use a value that contains `2`,`6`,`A` or `E` as the second number as this defines a locally administered MAC address.

```
x2:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
x6:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
xA:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
xE:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Comment: Cheers Iain, it works.